# Tab Application - Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, single-page-application

I am facing an issue with structuring my angular application. I need to have a tab application instead of routing, which is: whenever a user clicks a new link in the application, instead of routing the application to that component, it will:

1. check if the tab already opened, then select it
2. if not open, then add a new tab to the list of tabs in the navigation-tab and select it.
3. whenever a user clicks on the tab, the router changes to the new tab.
4. when hitting back in the browser, the system will select the previous tab, or open the last closed tab.

My initial plan is:

1. to remove the outlet from the application and add a [matTabNavBar].
2. listen to any change in the route and get the component and parameters related to the route.
3. use the route as a key for tabs (to check if the tab already exists or not).
4. if the component is not there, then dynamically create a new tab and add the component to it, and then select that tab.

Can you please help me with this, I need guidelines or best practices for all the steps (collecting ideas). and if there are some components or packages to help me achieve this. thanks

**Edit: To clear the example,**

let us say I have a list of items in the system loaded from the database, when I want to edit an Item I will be able to open it in its own tab. so I can open multiple items at the same time. and when I add a new item through the new tab, I should also be able to open that record in its own tab. they are not just a list of static tabs that I want to route between them

Comment: Hi, Did you solve the problem?

Comment: hi, yes I did. I will post it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to implement what I wanted by:

1. remove the routing-outlet from the app.
2. add a Mat-tab-group instead of it.
3. listen to the routing events in the app.
4. get the needed component name and parameter from the routing.
5. store it in a list of keys to be able to track what is opened and prevent opening the same component multiple times(depends on needs).
6. load the component in the UI dynamically using *ngComponentOutlet
7. passing the parameters using injectable class
8. manage events between tabs using singleton injectable service with Obseravables.

Instead of the outlet

```
<mat-tab-group [selectedIndex]="selectedTab" backgroundColor="primary" color="primary" (selectedTabChange)="selectedTabChanged($event)" style="height:100%;">
      <mat-tab label="Dashboard">
        Dashboard Component -- none closable tab, does not depend on routing.
      </mat-tab>
      <mat-tab *ngFor="let tab of tabsComponents; index as i">
        <ng-template mat-tab-label>
          {{tab.title | translate}}
          <button mat-icon-button class="close-icon"
                  (click)="closeTab($event,i)">
            <mat-icon class="close-icon ">
              close
            </mat-icon>
          </button>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="tab.component; injector:tab.params" ></ng-container>
      </mat-tab>
    </mat-tab-group>
```

The event Listener on routing:

```
this.routerEventSub = router.events.pipe(filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd))
  .subscribe((routeChange: NavigationEnd) => {
    this.layout.adjustLayout({ route: routeChange.url });

    let child = route.snapshot.firstChild.firstChild;
    console.log(child);
    if (this.tabsKeys.indexOf(routeChange.url) == -1) {
      this.tabsKeys.push(routeChange.url);

      let myParams: iTechParam = {
        _params: child.params,
        _queryParam: child.queryParams,
        _path:router.url
      }
      let params = Injector.create([
        { provide: iTechParam, useValue: myParams }
      ], this.inj);
      this.tabsComponents.push({ title: child.data['title'], component: child.component, params: params, path: router.url });
      this.selectedTab = this.tabsKeys.length;
    } else {
      this.selectedTab = this.tabsKeys.indexOf(routeChange.url) + 1;//+1 is because the dashboard tab, none-closable one
    }


  });
```

Variables:

```
tabsKeys: string[] = [];//store the keys of the opened tabs
tabsComponents: ITechTab[] = [];// stores information about the component in each tab
selectedTab = 0; // store the index of the selected tab
```

Close tab by index functionality:

```
closeTabByIndex(i: number) {
this.tabsKeys.splice(i, 1);
let removedtabs = this.tabsComponents.splice(i, 1);
if (this.router.url == removedtabs[0].path) {
  if (i == 0 && this.tabsComponents.length == 0) {
    this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
  } else {
    this.router.navigate([this.tabsComponents[i - 1].path]);
  }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Did this support lazy loading? Because you deleted `router-outlet`!

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but I used it with lazy loading for modules and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear why you think you have to get rid of routing in order to use tab navigation. Tab navigation and routing are not incompatible. To use MatTabNavBar and MatTabLink with routing, set up your application routing so that each "tab" is a route, add the router options to the mat-tab-link elements, and use router outlet to host the tab content. This should be much easier than what you have planned, since you won't need to worry about dynamic tab content "creation" and back button usage.

Here's selected code from a basic example, the full demo is on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qtgemx):

Template

```
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar [backgroundColor]="background">
    <a mat-tab-link routerLink="test-one" routerLinkActive #rla1="routerLinkActive" [active]="rla1.isActive">Test One</a>
    <a mat-tab-link routerLink="test-two" routerLinkActive #rla2="routerLinkActive" [active]="rla2.isActive">Test Two</a>
</nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Components

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

/**
 * @title Basic use of the tab nav bar with routing
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'tab-nav-bar-basic-example',
  templateUrl: 'tab-nav-bar-basic-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['tab-nav-bar-basic-example.css'],
})
export class TabNavBarBasicExample {}

@Component({
  selector: 'test-one',
  template: '<p>Test One</p>'
})
export class TestOne {}

@Component({
  selector: 'test-two',
  template: '<p>Test Two</p>'
})
export class TestTwo {}
```

App Module

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'test-one', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'test-one', component: TestOne },
  { path: 'test-two', component: TestTwo }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      appRoutes
    ),
    ...
  ],
  entryComponents: [TabNavBarBasicExample],
  declarations: [TabNavBarBasicExample, TestOne, TestTwo],
  bootstrap: [TabNavBarBasicExample],
  providers: []
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, removing the outlet was because I suspected that i will lose the changes I made in a single tab when I move to another tab. I will try your solution and if it worked I will mark it. thanks

Comment: this is a list of static tabs, please see my edit at the end of the question, what if I have a list of dynamic items and I want the capability to open multiple items at the  same time without losing the edited data when moving between tabs

Comment: It sounds like what you want has nothing to do with routing, so using the phrase "instead of routing" causes confusion. Think about editing your problem description to exclude any reference to routing and just explain what you are trying to achieve. That might help others understand better.